# Can't change name of app in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Long story short, I made an app, and now that it is done, I thought of a better name.

When I change the product name, it asks if I want to let it automatically change the name everywhere else. Unfortunately, after doing so, I deploy the app, but it still shows the old name on my device. I have tried many things to fix it, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where have you changed the app name? Did you change anything in your app's info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the app from the device and cleaning the targets on the project before deploying to the device again.

Comment: There was also something else, which I hadn't considered before until I added localization and the changes weren't showing, it's an option that clears the app data but I don't have a mac with me right now to say exactly how to do it, will update you when I get home :)

Comment: Try deleting the derived data in xcode- In Xcode go into the Organizer and under the Projects tab select your project from the left and then press delete next to Derived Data. Then restart xcode and repeat my first suggestion. I do this when I have changes in localization that aren't being shown in my app but I've never had a problem when changing the product name.